# How to hide siblings elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How would I hide rest of the categories when I click on one, and if I click again rest of the categories would appear again.

```
<?php if($slide1_row_cnt > 0){ ?>
<div class="item active">
<h4>Groups</h4>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slide1_result)) { ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">

                <p class="groups-list"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary groups-button" rel="/tasks/stock/stock-category-list.php?filter=<?php echo $row['id_stc']; ?>"><?php echo $row['description_stc']; ?></button></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- /Slide1 -->
```

Javascript:

```
    $('.groups-button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('p').siblings().toggle();

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Parent `p` has no siblings.

Comment: You should toggle the .row class

Comment: Perhaps `$(this).closest(".row")`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code shared

> `<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slide1_result)) {`

You are showing a list of rows, so you should hide the `row`s

```
$(this).closest('.row').siblings().toggle();
```